# leapyear python task for students

Tags: python, leap-year

new to teaching python to yr10's. This appears to work when telling the end user if their year is a leap year or not. But can someone please confirm if this code is working or the best way to do this. I realise there are probably different methods...Johnny:)

```
leapYear = int(input("what year is it?:"))

if (leapYear %4) == 0:
    print ("Thats a leap year")

elif (leapYear %100)==0:
    print ("thats not a leap year")

elif (leapYear % 400)== 0:
        print ("Thats a leap year")

else:
    print("thats not a leap year")
```

Comment: The best way to check if your code is working is to test it. Run it with all kind of inputs and check if it gives the right answer.

Comment: You code has logic errors, it will incorrectly identify `100` as a leap year. You need to consider the order in which you evaluate your conditions, e.g. if `leapYear = 400` then it matches all the conditions, which one should be evaluated first?

Comment: I think your elifs are redundant. Also you don't need the parentheses in your if.

Comment: If you are teaching programming, you may be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Answer (score 1):

Here are three alternative ways to check for a leap year in python, with the 2nd method being an improved version of your own attempt:

**1) Using [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html):**

```
import calendar

calendar.isleap(year)
```

**2) Similar to your own attempt but taking out the redundant steps and converting it into a method:**

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return year % 400 == 0
    return year % 4 == 0
```

**3) Check if the year provided has a a 29th of February using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):**

```
import datetime

def is_leap_year(year):
    try:
        datetime.date(year, 2, 29)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

**N.B.** Try to teach your students to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) in python code rather than [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).